# Firebase Cloud Messaging different keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Whats is the current key generated in `google_services.json` file when making the project. What is the difference between current key, web API key, and server key, and where can I find current key FCM console? I cannot find it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where FCM refers to "current key"?

Comment: }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "224788415279-s6jh7g39fbe*****************t0obk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDb7O*************eUv0V3pcmLJk-kks"
         
        }

Comment: this is google -services .json file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no documentation as of the moment that clearly discusses what values are found in the `google-services.json` file. Although this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083898/4625829)
pretty much gives you an idea on what it is and what it does.

As for the specific details you were asking for:

- **current key** - nothing is explicitly stated anywhere in the docs where it is used, however, among the 3 services where the `google-services.json` was originally used for before Firebase (*Google Sign-in, Analytics, GCM*), I'm guessing it would be between Google Sign-in and Analytics. As also mentioned by @DiegoGiorgini [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337038/4625829):

> The api_key value in google-services.json is not used by FCM. (it is used by other Firebase libraries)

So it can be for a separate Google non-Firebase or Firebase service.

- **Web API Key** - this one I haven't had a chance to use before. However, I've seen other posts wherein this specific API key is used often on Web apps related to Firebase (possibly also for Auth purposes?), but I'm not entirely sure.
- **Server Key** - as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials):

> A server key that authorizes your app server for access to Google services, including sending messages via Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I also tried to look around the Firebase Console on where the current key is visible, but it doesn't seem to be there.