# What is the difference between the two different API keys provided from FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

while creating an FCM project I noticed two different API-keys provided as follows;

1- in the google-servies.json file

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "the key"
        }
      ],
```

2- and another one called Web API Key in the app settings on firebase console

What is the difference between both of them and the usage?

Comment: App key/id: is used by the server to track how many API requests are made by a particular app in a day so that server can charge the client if request count exceeds the given threshold. WebAPi key is used for web notifiacation purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging different keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357782/firebase-cloud-messaging-different-keys)

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Web Api key is used to connect your server with google cloud to send message to your apps.
For example :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http

Comment: On the contrary the document states Server key is the key used by your server to send messages. Web API key I have no idea, I suspect it's used by Web clients to register their app for push notifications and is safe to expose to the public