# Firebase Authentication Failure on Node JS: NotAuthorizedError

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification through Firebase/Node JS. I currently have this code running on Heroku.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/push', function(request, response) {
  response.send("running");
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

// Planet Firebase API Key
var API_KEY = "AIz..."; // found at Project Settings > General > Web API Key
var fcm = new FCM(API_KEY);

var config = {
  apiKey: "AIz...",
  authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com", // Authentication > Sign-In Method > OAuth Redirect Domains
  databaseURL: "https://XXX.firebaseio.com/", // Database > Url at the top
  storageBucket: "gs://XXX.appspot.com", // Storage > Url at the top
};
var firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child('notifications');
  requests.on('child_changed', function(requestSnapshot) {
        var objectAdded = requestSnapshot.val();
        var uid = receiver["uid"]
        var notificationMessage = objectAdded["message"]
        sendNotificationToUser(uid, notificationMessage);
  }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
  });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(receiverID, notificationMessage) {
    var message = { 
        to: '/notifications/'+receiverID,       
        notification: {
            title: "App Title", 
            body: notificationMessage,
            badge: 1
        }
    };

    fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
        if (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        } else {
            console.log("Something has gone wrong! Error: " + err);
        }
    });
}

// start listening
listenForNotificationRequests();
```

Whenever `fcm.send()` is called, I get back:

```
Something has gone wrong! Error: NotAuthorizedError
```

This leads be to believe Firebase isn't initializing correctly, but I've checked the links and keys multiple times. What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error response?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. This is all it gives me.

Comment: Did you try it out? My answer I mean. Were you able to send a message after using the Server Key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, I noticed this part (specially the comment):

```
// Planet Firebase API Key
var API_KEY = "AIz..."; // found at Project Settings > General > Web API Key
var fcm = new FCM(API_KEY);
```

You're probably receiving an [401 - Authentication Error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

When using FCM, you should always use the **Server Key** and not the Web API Key.
 This is also visible in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/):
Project Settings > *Cloud Messaging* > Server Key.

<sub>See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358530/4625829) for an idea about the different keys.</sub>

Comment: It didn't seem to help. I'm still getting authentication errors.

Comment: ©user1072264 Odd. Can you try sending via a simple cURL and see if the issue is still the same?