# Does googleservices.json file in firebase contain any sensitive data?

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an existing xamarin android application which uses GCM client for pushing notification using Azure Notification Hub. GCM server and client API's are deprecating on April 11,2019. Can i continue using GCM.client library with FCM server? If yes, do i need to modify the existing code

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm), it is mentioned to add googleservices.json file in android application. I want to know whether file contains any sensitive data. Can i register my device with FCM using the sender ID of android project added in FCM?

Comment: My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358530/4625829) might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of google-services.json containing only public information.  All of those strings get baked into your app by the gradle plugin that processes it.  The protection for your app currently happens via the Google Play services app that's installed on almost all devices.  That's why you're asked for your SHA-1 signing key during signup.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the existing GCM client broadcast receiver for receiving GCM push notification using the Firebase configuration. In the cloud message setting in the Firebase configuration, you could see a legacy server api key with which you can try sending push notification from GCM.

However I will recommend you to do the FCM configuration using the googleservices.json file in android application. This will not add any sensitive data and you can register your device Id using the broadcast receivers where you can get the push token.